# Hibernate association mapping

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a bike rental system project. I am able to do CRUD operations via Rest API on Bike, and Customer and create a Contract object. For this, I have exposed CRUD endpoints(s) for

- /bike
- /customer
- /contract

The POST /contract/final endpoint should return a complete contract overview with contractid, bike details, and customer

The association I am using is as below

```
class Contract {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private id;
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="customerId")
private Customer customer;
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="bikeId")
private Bike bike; 
}

class Customer{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "customer_id")
private Long customerId;
private String firstName;
}

class Bike{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "bike_id")
private long bikeId;
private String model;
}
```

So I just want to be able to create/modify the bike|customer records and create a contract with the already created customer(s) and bike(s).

As of now, the contract request will create the customer and bike records apart from records created separately using /customer, /bike endpoints - which I do not want.

Is the association mapping I have used correct for this requirement? What should ideally be the relationship between these entities given the below contraints?

- One customer can have many contracts but one contract will have only one customer
- One bike can have many contracts but one contract will have only one bike

  How can I make use of the existing customer/bike records while creating a contract?

Comment: You have to make model of class and you have to change your mapping from unidirectional mapping to bidirectional mapping.

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej It is not a good idea. For example, if people leave in a `Country`. Does `Country` have to have a list of all people?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do you want to have the ability to change a `Bike` model when you create a new `Contract`? Obviously no! `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` is about such changes. So throw it away.
2. Do you want to load all the `Contract` data, like   a `Bike`, when you load a `Contract`? It is not so obvious, but my advice don't do this! Let's change `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` to `fetch=FetchType.LAZY`.
3. You use two strategies to generate an `id` — `strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE`, `strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY`. Use only one.
4. Don't use a primitive type for an `id`. Change `long bikeId` to `Long bikeId`.
5. `@JoinColumn` specifies a database column name, not a class property. Change `@JoinColumn(name="customerId")` to `@JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID")`. Use uppercase for column names.

```java
class Contract {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Customer customer;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BIKE_ID")
    private Bike bike;
    
}
```

Assign existing `Bike` and `Customer` to the `Contract`, using `getReferenceById()` method. It doesn't hit a database at all.

```java
Customer customer = customerRepository.getReferenceById(customerId);
contract.setCustomer(customer);
```

Another way is to use a transient customer.

```java
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setId(customerId);
contract.setCustomer(customer);
```

But standard repository `save()` method uses `merge()`. So it will be an additional SQL request to load a customer. You can use custom repository with pure `save()` method to avoid this
https://vladmihalcea.com/best-spring-data-jparepository/

Comment: Thanks @v.ladynev. However, `customerRepository.getReferenceById(1)` is returning null even when I have a customer record with Id = 1 in the table. I have annotated the service class with @Transactional. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: @continuousLearner You don't need `@Transactional` for now. Each repository method has a separate transaction. `customerRepository.getReferenceById(1L)` returns an object, even it doesn't exist in the database. the `EntityNotFoundException` is thrown when such object state is first accessed. Update your question please.

Comment: My bad, the postman request had the stale id which caused EntityNotfoundException. I am able to save now. Thanks so much for the guidance!